# Strange issue with custom font-face and Font Awesome font on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, font-face, font-awesome

I have an issue working with font-face on mobile devices.

I have the following custom font-face definition for Rex font

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'RexBold';
             src: url('RexBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('RexBold.otf')  format('opentype'),
                  url('RexBold.woff') format('woff'), url('RexBold.ttf')  format('truetype'), url('RexBold.svg#RexBold') format('svg');
                  font-weight: normal;
                  font-style: normal;
           }
```

All files are accessible from the client side and not giving 404 or anything like that

Everything works under desktop browser (except for IE 6 and 7 of course. IE 9 and up works fine.) but it is not working on mobile devices (Tested on Android 2.3, 4.4 and IOS 6)

At first, I thought that was an error in generated definition for svg font (the `#RexBold` part) but the definition was correct - #RexBold is the correct reference for the font-face in the svg file.

Then I assumed that my web server (nginx 1.6) is serving wrong mime-types for fonts. And I updated my `mime.types` configuration file according to [HTML5 Boilerplate config](https://github.com/darktable/html5-boilerplate-server-configs/blob/master/nginx-mime.types)

But that also doesn't work. By the way  Font Awesome (4.0) on my site  is not working for mobile too, but it is working on [their official site](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). I used their [guide](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) for connecting Font Awessome to the site (using Bootstrap CDN) and I am using the following css rule:

```
ul.fa-icon-check li:before {    
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f14a';
    margin:0 5px 0 -21px;
    font-size: large;
}
```

Can anyone provide me with a clue what can be wrong with this?
Thanks in advance! Here is the link to my site - http://study-in-japan-guide.com/ru/

Comment: Do you have a link we can look at?

Comment: Yes. Here is the link - http://study-in-japan-guide.com/ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fonts.css file (http://study-in-japan-guide.com/themes/heywater_edited/fonts/fonts.css) is not being loaded on a mobile. Therefore it's not loading the @font-face.

From a Desktop:
[image]

From a Mobile:
[image]

Comment: That's very strange.... But how did you get that output? I know only one way to debug mobile sites on mobile devices - through google chrome remote debugging. But I didn't tested that yet. I want to reproduce it.

Comment: @JohnGray I used a great plugin for firefox - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/go-mobile. It's great as you can still use all other debug tools such as firebug etc.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day. At least half of it. Another half I will have to spend figuring out why my CMS is not generating all my new css link tags for mobile browsers.